# Is this a WordPress security bug?

Tags: security, bug

```
<?php
if ( ! is_admin() ) return;
echo 'You should not see this if you\'re not logged in!';
?>
```

If you put this in a [mu-plugin](http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins), and go to your admin, e.g., `example.com/wp-admin/` while you are *not logged in*, should you be able to see the `echo`?

Comment: There's an error (') in your code.

Comment: Should be the following: `<?php if ( ! is_admin() ) return; echo "You should not see this if you're not logged in!"; ?>` You need to use double quotes if you are going to include special characters inside the echo

Comment: You can use `is_user_logged_in()` to check if user is logged in or not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're misinterpreting the `is_admin()` function.  It's not a tag to check whether or not the *user* is an admin, it's a template tag to check if you're on an admin page.

From the [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin):

> This Conditional Tag checks if the Dashboard or the administration panel is being displayed. This is a boolean function, meaning it returns either TRUE or FALSE.

You're facing a couple of issued here though.

1. If you attempt to go to `/wp-admin` while you're not logged in, WordPress will automatically redirect the page.  A request to `/wp-admin` is *really* a request to `/wp-admin/index.php`, a page non-logged-in users don't have permission to see in the first place.  So you'll be redirected to `/wp-admin/wp-login.php` which doesn't necessarily load your plugin code.
2. I say "doesn't necessarily load your plugin code" because I'm not sure.  From the looks of things you're `echo`/`return` exists in the global scope.  Really, this code should be wrapped in a function and hooked to a WordPress action.

Now, if you go to the `/wp-admin` page while you're *logged in*, `is_admin()` will evaluate to `true` you should be able to see the content of your `echo` statement just fine, assuming a couple of things:

1. No errors in your code (as both @amit and @Fraggy have pointed out, you have a typo - an unescaped `'` character.
2. That you're hooking things in at the right place.  You shouldn't just `echo` and `return` in the global scope because, really, there's no way to control *where* that `echo`/`return` will be happening.  You should place this code in a function.

### Important Note

If you ever do find a security hole or security-related bug in WordPress, you should [***report it to security@wordpress.org***](http://codex.wordpress.org/FAQ_Security#Where_do_I_report_security_issues.3F) rather than posting in a public forum like this.  This kind of responsible disclosure gives the team the chance to address and patch the issue before malicious hackers can read about it and exploit it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm aware that I need to hook in the right places, and test user capabilities. But the Codex is somewhat misleading in it's assertion *Dashboard or the administration panel is being displayed*. WP redirected me to login page once out of about ten times that I tried this. All other times showed the echo. Re: your note about reporting, I agree and normally wouldn't throw something out willy-nilly; I wanted to get guidance on this before posting to Trac. I didn't want to look stupid with something that is possibly a misunderstanding on my part.

Comment: One more note, I wasn't assuming that `is_admin()` meant Administrator. I *was* assuming it meant what the Codex said, the part in your quote: *Dashboard or the administration panel is being displayed*.

Comment: Yes, and `index.php` is the Dashboard. But if you're not logged in, you *should* be redirected to `wp-login.php`, which is *not* the Dashboard or an administrative panel.

Comment: *Should* be redirected. But that is not the case. :(

Comment: If you're not being redirected to the login page when you're not logged in, then something else is going on. Either due to this plugin or another you have on the site. In either case, that's beyond the scope of this particular question. Perhaps [open a new one](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) - "Why are not-logged in users failing to be redirected to wp-login.php?"

Comment: I'm not trying to be argumentative, but this is easily replicable on a fresh install of 3.5., using *only* the code in question. It's not about any plugin development, or about why I'm not being redirected. There are no conflicts, this behavior is strictly core + the above code.

Comment: Your original question: "Is this a security bug?" Answer: no.  That's why I suggested opening a *new* question to ask about the redirect.

Answer (score 3):

> *The [`is_admin()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin) only checks for if current visitor is on admin page or not.*

To block any non admin user from visting any admin page use [`current_user_can();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/current_user_can) function. Here's an example to check if current user is not a admin.

```
if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
    echo 'You should not see this if you\'re not logged in!';
}
```

> **#1 Update -**
>
> [`is_user_logged_in()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in) - 
>   There's a function to check if current visiting user is logged in or not, You can use that. Here's an updated example -
>
> ```
> if ( ! is_user_logged_in() ) {
>    echo 'You should not see this if you\'re not logged in';
> }
> ```

Comment: But, according to [is_admin()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_admin) in the Codex "*This Conditional Tag checks if the Dashboard or the administration panel is being displayed*"

Comment: refer to other answer by @EAMann to know more about `is_admin()`

Comment: @AKTed yep, `is_admin()` checks for current page type not the visiting user's.